# Fixed Length Gaussian pdf

Tags: pr.probability

In a research problem about detection theory I faced with the following question.
How can I find the conditional Gaussian probability density function

$$ f({\mathbf w} \; | \; \|{\mathbf w}\|^2)$$
where $\mathbf w$ is  an $N$ dimensional random vector with Gaussian distribution  with Zero mean and co-variance matrix $\mathbf I$ ($N\times N$ identity matrix) and also $\| {\mathbf w}\| $ is the 2-Norm of vector $\mathbf w$?.

Comment: this is a uniform distribution: every $w$ of length $||w||$ is equally probable.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2613183/fixed-length-gaussian-pdf/2613205#2613205